# Java set response content type to several servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I found all servlet classes in a project haven't been set a content-type, if I added 'response.setContentType' to every file of those, there would be about 60 files changed. I'm wondering if there is a simple way to solve this problem, that is, not to add too many same lines?

Comment: Refactor your code to extract all the common functionality like setting up the response. Without concrete examples, it's hard to give a more detailed explanation. Note that these kinds of things are exactly why people use existing web-frameworks built on top of the servlets API: to take care of the "house keeping" so they can focus on the business logic.

Comment: I think you are right, but unluckily I cannot refactor the code at this moment for some reason..

Comment: Then, touching those 60 files it is, I guess.